# Responsive Mobile Design looks different on on other devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a question for a problem.
I made a Responsive Design for our Shop,
the Problem is when I test the mobile usability and the design (I'm testing with Browserstack)
everything looks fine.
When I'm testing it on my own phone (iPhone cases) it looks also fine even on my htc u11.
But when my boss looks to check on his phone (iPhone 11 Pro) he sees some issues and told me to fix it. I can't comprehend why?

The main problem is the text description.

the SHop Url for this category : https://www.subtel.de/Notebook-Zubehoer/?view_type=grid_view

Here are some screenshots and my html/css

css:

```
.productinfo_grid_view{
    line-height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    height: 34px;
    white-space: normal;
    grid-column: 1/7;
    grid-row: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 12%;
}
```

html:

```
<span class="productinfo_grid_view">
    <a itemprop="url" id="[{$testid}]" href="[{$_productLink}]" title="[{$_sTitle}]"><span itemprop="name">[{$_sTitle}]</span></a>
</span>
```

as you can see its nothing special,
when you see the screenshots my boss gave me and the screenshot from my phone and browserstack. I'm confused has anyone a hint for me how to solve this kind of problem ?

1st smaller image is the screenshot from my boss the second image is how it should look and how it looks on my phone too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the smaller screenshot has more text in the description, that might be the issue, did you test it on the bigger screenshot device also with that much text?

Comment: try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow). 
The problem seems to be the text size of the description.

Comment: its the same article with the same description @RamondeVries , the overflow does not work i don't know why.

Comment: Please share URL

Comment: You have to remove fixed height of text description and add text limit for description.

Comment: https://www.subtel.de/Notebook-Zubehoer/?view_type=grid_view

Comment: @Jaba if you want to keep overflow hidden to limit the space. Try adding `display: inline-block;` see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have set a fixed height to your description.

Try removing `height: 34px;`

EDIT:
or if you want to keep a fixed height and the overflow hidden

Try adding `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like website is Zooming. Please disable zoom on a mobile web page using `<meta>` tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content= "width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

**OR**

You have to **remove fixed height** of text description and add **text limit** for description.

Answer (score 0):

Please update `height: 30px;` to `height: 34px;`

```
.productinfo_grid_view{  
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: this should also work yes, but i don't think that its the best solution ?

Comment: Because the height is extra as per the text description. Please do and test it.

Comment: ill try it of course thank you  , it cuts of a bit of letters like y or g , maybe a bit of everything could help me here from your help and the help of the other comments. i'm testing a bit right now and let you know what helped me thanks a lot